# Use inverse cos in lambda function without addtional module

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, lambda

### Background

I am doing a task on codewar, which asks me to use **`1 line`** **lambda function** to finish it. Specifically, I want to use `math.acos` in my **lambda function**.

```
# Code contains 2 lines, so it will fail
import math # line 1
fun1 = lambda x: math.acos(x) # line 2

fun1(1)
```

Out:

> 0.0

The above code fails because it contains 2 lines. What I want is using similar function inside `lambda function`:

```
fun1 = lambda x: XXXX # line 1
fun1(1)
```

Out:

> 0.0

### My question

**Is it possible to use `math.acos` in lambda function?** If it is not, maybe I should change my idea to finish the task.

Comment: The `import` does not need to be part of the `lambda` express. Just do it at the top of the script.

Comment: You are right, but strange usage is helpful during code golf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
fun1 = lambda x: __import__('math').acos(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

No need even for a lambda here:

```py
from math import acos as fun1
```

But if you do need it to be a lambda, you can use a semicolon `;` to put it on the same line as the `import`:

```py
import math; fun1 = lambda x: math.acos(x)
```